# Bounty expired, no answers given, what now?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have a question [Was there a similar chapter to Uncharted 3: “The Chateau” in any of the previous Uncharted games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61376/was-there-a-similar-chapter-to-uncharted-3-the-chateau-in-any-of-the-previous) that I put up a bounty for. Unfortunately I received no answers and now the bounty has expired. Along with my rep dropping 100 points.

Is it consented that the rep I put up for bounty is now lost into the abyss or should something else happen to my question?

Comment: yes your bounty is gone, and yes you'll be nagged to award the bounty for 24 hours after it closes even though there's no answers.  I have a [meta request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120858/bounty-grace-period-shouldnt-be-there-if-no-answers-are-posted) to fix that nagging issue but its still open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reputation spent on a bounty is lost immediately upon placing the bounty, and there is no way to get it back. Either it gets awarded to someone (who isn't you), or it disappears entirely.

Quoting from [the FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty):

> In any case, you will always give up the amount of reputation
>   specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow
>   up and award your bounty to the best answer!

Think of placing a bounty as paying an advertising fee with your reputation to draw attention to your question. Whether or not it was able to get a *good* answer, the advertising occurred.

For more information about bounties, [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) is pretty thorough.

---

Your particular question might not have received an answer simply because the real answer might be "No, there wasn't anything just like that in the previous games", and there's no one willing to take the time to prove that. Proving a negative generally requires a lot more effort than proving a positive. For someone to write a good answer that says "No", they'd pretty much have to list off every scene from the previous games just to prove they don't match.

Comment: Can you award the bounty to an answer you post under any circumstances?

Comment: @NickT Nope. Never. Well, I think you can, but you won't earn rep from it.

Comment: @NickT I believe you used to be able to, with it counting as 0 points, but now you just plain can't since that was confusing.