# What to do if I don't get an answer even after starting a bounty?

Tags: discussion, questions

So, last month, I asked this question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303328/why-cant-i-rebattle-the-trainers-i-could-in-pok%C3%A9mon-black-and-white) about a problem I had playing my Pokémon Black game. I got a comment that the emulator I was using didn't support the game and another suggesting I used an AR code. But the only actual answer I got doesn't even solve my problems. I ended up starting a bounty; however no one actually answered the question in time. Not even during the grace period. I know my reputation is gone, but what should I do about my question? Should I close it due to lack of attention? I worked so hard to get an answer; even 3 edits were put there. Basically, what can I do about it now?

A [similar question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/bounty-expired-no-answers-given-what-now) was asked, however, it was about the reputation from the bounty, not what to do about the question.

Comment: Sometimes we just don't know the answer. It may be that not enough people here have gone through that to help you out. I have used the same emulator for the same game, but haven't gotten as far as you. My only suggestion would be to maybe try a different emulator to see if it is a problem specific to that emulator.

Comment: Will using another emulator delete my progress for the same exact rom I am using?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue In my experience, yes. Unless both emulators use the same saving method (unlikely), you'd lose progress.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Leave the question - there is no reason to remove or close it.**

There are a few reasons to leave it:

1. You may get an answer that works eventually!
2. Someone else on the internet may one day have the same problem and will have your question to look to (or in the case that they asked a duplicate, we can close it appropriately).  Despite having no accepted answer (yet), someone else could try what was suggested, and it may work for them.
3. Although you already have, someone else may offer a bounty on your question - someone who is likely burning to know an answer to the problem.  This should draw more attention in again.

Looking at your question, it seems pretty good to me.  I don't think much more can be done in terms of editing it.  When you do edit a post, it bumps it to the top of the "Active" list on the site.  If you can edit the post to include more information (like you have been) it'll bumped it back to the top, and that on the homepage of Arqade as well!

You can also try sharing your question to social media sites.  Click the "Share" button below your question, and choose the site, or copy the link and post it where ever you like.  Note that when you place a bounty on a question, it is [automatically tweeted](https://twitter.com/TheArqade/status/847535482141630465) to the Arqade Twitter page (though it looks like it took 4 days after you placed your bounty for you question to get tweeted - not sure if this is suppose to take this long or not).  If a question gets hot enough, it'll get tweeted to our Twitter automatically as well.  You can see in the [revision history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/303328/revisions) of the post if it's been tweeted or not.

As Dragonrage said in their comment, sometimes a question is just not answerable - at least to the people who use the site.  It's possible that you're the first person to ever experience this issue, making your question very unique.

I'll leave you on this note which is from our [Help Pages](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) (you've probably already seen this):

> #### What should I do if no one answers my question?
>
> First, make sure you’ve [asked a good question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.
>
> If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by [offering a bounty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/bounty) on any question more than two days old.